# Why is EF6 saying I need to apply migrations that were already applied?

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-6

I am trying to add a migration, by running the following command in PMC `add-migration usernotes`.  
 Anways, I see all of my migrations in the _MigrationHistory table, but I am getting an error when I try to run the command saying 
 `Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: <all my migrations that were already applied>. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration` 
 **What I have tried**
 Specifying the configuration name with `-ConfigurationTypeName CONFIGNAME` (My config name is different that that fyi).
 `Enable-Migration` which results with the PMC telling me that migrations are already enabled
  Uninstall and re-installing EF
 Setting startup project
 Rebuilding project
 Moving all migrations so EF won't see them anymore
Specify connection string with `-ConnectionString`

Comment: you didnt say, you applied 'updatedatabase' that's the command to apply a migration.

Comment: @Holger sorry, all the "pending" migrations have already been applied. This error happens when I am just trying to add migrations. I haven't gotten to the point to where I can update the db

Comment: What happens if you try 'update-database'? Have you tried that.

Comment: @PeterSmith this is a db that multiple people use, so I can't allow the chance to blow it up. Plus, since all of those migrations are already applied, it wouldnt do anything, right?

Comment: With respect @jfiggins, should you be doing migrations on a live database? Why not back it up and make a local copy for testing.

Comment: @PeterSmith this is a test db, just multiple people at our work use it

Comment: You will find it hard to resolve this unless you can get exclusive access. There are many things that you can try but you need to be able to 'damage' the database and then restore it.

Comment: @PeterSmith I will try to get a backup and do it locally on my computer. I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: Look at the __MigrationHistory Table in the database. You can check if really all migrations have been applied. You say so, but you need a way to proof it. Sometimes you just have different databases, and you connect to the wrong one.

Comment: @Holger Yeah all the migrations were applies, check the db. Connection string issue with the app not decrypting the password right

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the way the connection string was working is that it was pieced together on startup, and when I put it all as one, like this: `public string ConnStr = "Server=sever_name;Database=db_name;User Id = userid; Password=password;";`, it fixed the issue.